# Подключение несколько scss файлов к стартовому шаблону vue cli

Tags: webpack, scss

У меня есть несколько scss файлов, с миксинами и прочими настройками для проекта. Мне нужно подключить их к стартовому шаблону vue cli. Как это можно сделать? Мне необходимо, что бы эти миксины и стартовые настройки вроде font-face распространялись на все веб приложение. Для сборки использую webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что нам нужно будет сделать, так это установить некоторые зависимости, выполняем команду:
Если используете NPM :

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass style-loader --save-dev
```

Eсли используете yarn:

```
yarn add sass-loader node-sass style-loader
```

Следующее, нужно добавить настройки приведенные ниже в Webpack, сами строки находятся в “build/webpack.base.conf.js” файле.

Важно! Отмечу то, что наши SCSS файлы находятся в “src/assets/scss”.

```
   resolve: {
     extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.scss'],
     alias: {
       'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
       '@': resolve('src'),
       styles: resolve('src/assets/scss')
     }

}
```

Теперь можно использовать SCSS в своих проектах, для этого нужно добавить не хитрую опцию lang = “scss” в секцию со стилями, вот так:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Для того, чтобы импортировать .scss файл нужно будет прописать “@import”, например:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 @import '../assets/scss/main';
</style>
```

[Источник](https://medium.com/@serg.gavel/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-sass-scss-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-vue-js-10542b3a1b09) и сам пользовался не раз этим методом.

Comment: Для того, чтобы импортировать .scss файл нужно будет прописать “@import”, например:

<style lang="scss" scoped>
 @import '../assets/scss/main';
</style>

Было достаточно этого. Благодарю.

Comment: Написал все полностью, мало ли на каком шаге застярял :)

Comment: А еще возникла проблема, туториал отличный. Вот только у меня нет папки build c webpack.base.conf.js  И теперь не совсем понятно как ее создавать.